# PHP : select all row but one?

Tags: php, sql, joomla, row

I got some trouble with some part of PHP code. It's part of a CMS' module (Hikashop/Joomla).

Here are the lines:

```
    echo $this->payment->display('new_payment_method',
                                 $row->order_payment_method,
                                 $row->order_payment_id,false);
} else {
    $text = JText::sprintf('PAY_WITH_X',$this->payment->
    getName($row->order_payment_method,$row->order_payment_id));
```

for the part `$row->order_payment_id` I would like to have all rows but one. Is there a way to make it simple ???

Comment: It is not very clear what you are requesting. Do you want this to happen in the MySQL (hence the SQL tag you added) or you want to just exclude it out of the results? If it's the first, we need to see some SQL.

Comment: Question not clear ? what is trying ?

Answer (score 0):

Without testing the code (never played with Joomla), but the basic idea would be:

```
if( $row->order_payment_id != "unwanted_value_here" )
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

That would be the logical approach.